# Can QEMU/KVM+OCFS2 be configured to punch holes in sparse image files when files are deleted in the guest?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, sparse-files

I'm using sparse raw image files for guest VMs and OCFS2 on the host (local-only, not clustered) for the `reflink` feature. I understand from Googling around that OCFS2 is [one of the filesystems that can punch holes](http://lwn.net/Articles/415889/) back into sparse files.

If I understand correctly, [it may be possible](http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2012/02/15/discard-hole-punching-and-trim/) (and apparently [can be achieved with XFS](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-08/msg02816.html)) to combine this feature with TRIM/discard support in the guest machines so that when files in the guest are deleted, space on the host is automatically reclaimed. However despite much experimentation, I haven't been able to demonstrate this working.

Is this possible, and if it depends on versions of the kernel and/or QEMU, what are the minimum versions I need? Also have I missed anything with the configuration? I've:

- mounted the (ext4) guest filesystem with the `discard` option in `/etc/fstab`
- tried the current beta of Debian Wheezy for host and guest, and CentOS 6.2 for host
- tried running `fstrim` on the guest (I get `FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported`—but I'm not 100% sure if this is relevent)
- tried `bus=ide` and `bus=virtio` (with CentOS 6.2 host)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to recover space by using virtio-scsi devices and specifying discard=unmap in the libvirt definition for the disk.

I haven't tried this in CentOS/RHEL but I did get this to work in later versions of Fedora. I wrote [a blog post about it](http://dustymabe.com/2013/06/11/recover-space-from-vm-disk-images-by-using-discardfstrim/).

I would say to give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: I won't be able to test exactly as I've moved away from raw files (I'm using qed now), but thanks.